# Error Loading R (RStudio Desktop for Windows)

Tags: r, rstudio, cran

I am currently learning R and need to install RStudio Desktop (Windows 11 64-bit) for my current learning requirement.

I had already installed R (4.2.2) from CRAN for the RStudio (2022.12.0+353) to work. But after i installed RStudio and opened it. This happened:

[image: Error Loading R]

I'm installing both R and RStudio on its default location and already tried the browse button on the RStudio to directly choose R, but it's still showing the error.

[image: Choose R Installation]

Thank you for the help!

I tried to choose R directly by clicking the [Browse...] button from the "Choose R Installation" window but it is still showing the error and won't open RStudio

Comment: Have you tried running R outside of RStudio? You can look for the application or you can you the command line (launch the R interpreter in the  command line by typing R (capitalized, no other characters) and press enter. Test it out by adding or something (the prompt in command line will change to >>> or something along those lines). If R works then it might be worth it to uninstall and re-install RStudio.

Comment: @Kat Hello! Thanks for answering. I already tried running R outside of RStudio and it still works fine. I tried to re-install RStudio several times but the problem still persists.

Comment: [Check out this recent flood of info about the latest version of RStudio.](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12452) I think if you install even the previous version, it may work out. You can find the previous version [here](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/older-versions/).

Comment: @Kat Well thanks a lot for the information! I'll try to install the previous version now and I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: @Kat I tried installing the previous version and it works! Thank you, Kat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by reverting back to an older version of RStudio.

Comment: Hello Skye! What version of RStudio did you use to make it work?

Comment: Hi Atthoriq! I think it's just one version back. The information below was copied from my RStudio, hope this helps!

RStudio 2022.07.2+576 "Spotted Wakerobin" Release (e7373ef832b49b2a9b88162cfe7eac5f22c40b34, 2022-09-06) for Windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

Comment: I installed your version of RStudio (2022.07.2 + 576 "Spotted Wakerobin") and it worked! Thank you Skye for the solution!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).